# django form submit not working

Tags: python, django, forms, post, get

I have created for interface for users to filter the content from database by values.

Class in View

```
class FilterCommentsUIView(TemplateView,FormView):
template_name = 'allcomments.html'
form_class = CommentFilterForm

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(FilterCommentsUIView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    logger.debug("Entered context data")
    logger.debug(self.request.method)
    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        form = CommentFilterForm(self.request.POST)
        loggeer.debug("Entered POST")
        if form.is_valid():
            logger.debug("Entered is valid")
            parenttype = self.request.POST['pchoice']
            users  = self.request.POST.get('users')
            tags   = self.request.POST.get('tags')
            fdate  = self.request.POST.get('fdate')
            tdate  = self.request.POST.get('tdate')
            typeuser = self.request.POST.get('typeuser')
            query  = self.request.POST.get('query')
            userid = User.objects.get(username ='pavan')

            comments = Item.objects.all().filter(user = userid.id).order_by('-created')
            paginator = Paginator(comments,20)
            page = self.request.GET.get('page')
            try:
                comments = paginator.page(page)
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                comments = paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:
                comments = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

            context['comments']=comments
            context['form']=CommentFilterForm

        else:
             logger.debug("Entered isvalid else")
             logger.debug(form.errors)

    else:
        logger.debug("Entered Else of POST")

        form = CommentFilterForm()
        comments = Item.objects.all().order_by('-created')
        paginator = Paginator(comments, 20)
        page = self.request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            comments = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            comemnts = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            comments = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context['comments']=comments
        context['form']= form

    return context
```

When i click on submit button it does not enter the POST if section. It always goes to else part. What am i doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance for help.
Pavan

Comment: Could you post the HTML form to verify that the method is set to 'POST'?

Comment: <form class="form-horizontal well" method="POST" action="commentsfilter">{% csrf_token %}{{ form }}<input type="submit" value="Filter" /></form>

Comment: Missing csrf_exempt decoration or {{ csrf_token }} in template?

Comment: Why are you doing this in `get_context_data` and not just using `form_valid`?

Comment: I am using class based view and Template View. I looked up online for some code snippets. I followed the same way.

Comment: @user3678334 You have a typo on this line loggeer.debug("Entered POST") -> loggeer insted of logger

Comment: @wolendranh I updated the code.. Yet its not POSTING.

Comment: Can you please also print/log the form.non_field_errors? Either add `{{ form.non_field_errors }}` to your template or add `logger.debug(form.non_field_errors)` to your `else` branch. Please let us know what the results are. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This needs to be done in the form_valid() method, not the get_context_data method.  get_context_data is just used to provide extra data (aka context) to the template during the request.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you have issues with the fact all your code is in `get_context_data`. In all actuality you don't even need to use `get_context_data` to accomplish what you are trying to do.

From what I can see you are trying to get comments on the page. Then submit a form back to the page and get a filtered out set of comments returned, and rendered. Here is a view solution that better does what you want except using generic class based views more fully.

```
class FilterCommentsUIView(FormMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'allcomments.html'
    form_class = CommentFilterForm
    paginate_by = 20
    model = Item
    context_object_name = 'comments'
    qs_kwargs = {}

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Handles POST requests, instantiating a form instance with the passed
        POST variables and then checked for validity.
        """
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(FilterCommentsUIView, self).get_queryset()
        if self.qs_kwargs:
            return qs.filter(**self.qs_kwargs)
        return qs

    def form_valid(self, form):
        parenttype = form.cleaned_data['pchoice']
        users  = form.cleaned_data('users')
        tags   = form.cleaned_data('tags')
        fdate  = form.cleaned_data('fdate')
        tdate  = form.cleaned_data('tdate')
        typeuser = form.cleaned_data('typeuser')
        query  = form.cleaned_data('query')
        userid = User.objects.get(username ='pavan')

        # put logic here on what to expand into a filter on orm
        self.qs_kwargs['user'] = userid.id

        self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())
```

I haven't run this code, but this is how it should work.

This uses the `FormMixin` to give us form functionality along with the `ListView` with your `Item` class. This takes care of querying for your objects and paginating them, along with a basic `get` method.

Also the `ListView` inherits from `TemplateResponseMixin` which has your template code so you don't need to inherit from `TemplateView` so in the code above I removed that.

Based on the very nature of the base `View` class which `ListView` uses the dispatch method detects whether you are doing a `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`, etc... As such it calls the appropriate method on the view. In this case since you are doing a `POST` it will call the post method in the view. The `FormView`'s implementation of `post` is this:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    Handles POST requests, instantiating a form instance with the passed
    POST variables and then checked for validity.
    """
    form_class = self.get_form_class()
    form = self.get_form(form_class)
    if form.is_valid():
        return self.form_valid(form)
    else:
        return self.form_invalid(form)
```

Since we aren't using `FormView`, but are using `FormMixin` We need to include it.

So all it does is get the form class you set in `self.form_class` instantiates it, then checks if it is valid. If so calls the `form_valid` method. Thus we overrode the `form_valid` method above. Since it passes in the form with it and it has cleaned all the data we can use the normal django form of `form.cleaned_data`. This helps us with security so we should use that to get back information.

In the last part of the `form_valid` method we are returning `render_to_response`. Normally this just redirects to `self.success_url`, but we want to render the page so we just do a render_to_response and pass it in our context data. We call `self.get_context_data()` because that is what builds all the data for paginating our comments that we need.

Now comes a bit of the `magic`. if you notice there is `self.qs_kwargs`. This is something that is not normally in GCBV's, but something I added for this implementation. Here is where you would put logic to build a dictionary of filters to run in your orm call in `get_queryset`. We pack it into the dictionary, because in the `get_queryset` method above we unpack it all, if needed, to do our filtering.

So if you have:

`qs_kwargs = {'user': user.id, 'created__gt': somedate}`

And you do:

`qs.filter(**qs_kwargs)` or `Item.objects.filter(**qs_kwargs)`

That is roughly the same as doing:

`qs.filter(user=user.id, created__gt=somedate)` or `Item.objects.filter(user=user.id, created__gt=somedate)`

Finally, if you pay attention to the `get_queryset` method you notice it returns back all results, like you want, unless `qs_kwargs` is populated which happens from the `form_valid` method. So it takes in to account both `GET` and `POST` on the page.

Also to keep things simple your html should look something like this:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <div>
            {% for comment in comments %}
            {{ comment }}
            {% endfor %}
             <ul class="pagination">
                {% if page_obj.has_previous() %}
                <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a></li>
                {% endif %}
                {% for pg in paginator.page_range %}
                {% if page_obj.number == pg %}
                <li class="active"><a href="?page={{ pg }}">{{ pg }}</a></li>
                {% else %}
                <li><a href="?page={{ pg }}">{{ pg }}</a></li>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                {% if page_obj.has_next() %}
                <li><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number() }}">Next</a></li>
                {% endif %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <input type="submit" value="submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tested the above code. I am not able to display crispy form in the template {% crispy form %} . forms.py is at http://dpaste.com/151ZN1R . I think i am not able to create a context and pass it to Template . Can you guide me here ?

Comment: Only thing I can think is to make sure you have `{% load crispy_forms_tags %}` at the top of your template file to load crispyform tags so that can work.

Comment: Yes I have that {% load crispy_forms_tags %} at top of template file. I get error as "Failed lookup for key [form] in u" VariableDoesNotExist .

Comment: def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context =                                  super(FilterCommentsUIView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = CommentFilterForm()
        return context

Comment: when i add above code for get_context_data form is displayed but when i submit form it throws 'FilterCommentsUIView' object has no attribute 'object_list' error.I guess if this is solved application will work.. Thank you ..